# Вращение элемента Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать анимацию вращения обычного 2d элемента(div-а), на 1080 градусов влево (к примеру).

Comment: а css -ом можно сделать?

Comment: Мне нужен именно JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const $div = $('div');

const MAX_ANGLE = -1080;
const speed = 10; // скорость вращения
let angle = 0;
const animate = () => {
  if (angle >= MAX_ANGLE) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  } else {
    angle = MAX_ANGLE;
  }

  $div.css('transform', `rotate(${angle}deg)`);
  angle -= speed;
}

animate();
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #333;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: А как скорость отрегулировать?

Comment: Скорость регулируется через `angle--`, можете написать `angle -= 0.5`, будет медленнее, щас поправлю ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает, всё супер.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.spinner').toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.spinner{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,yellow 50%,orange 50%);
  transform-origin:center;
  transition:all .7s ease
}
.spinner.active{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spinner"></div>
<button>Крутануть</button>
```